# sys.exit() causes an unexpected error causing the "repl process to die unexpectedly"

Tags: python, exit-code, sys

I am using repl.it to code a login/registration screen. The code in Python is below:

```
while True:
    print("""
============MAIN MENU================
                   *Welcome*
                   1. Register
                   2. Login
                   3. Quit
""")
    
    x=input("Enter choice:")
    if int(x)==1:
        register()
    elif int(x)==2:
        login()
    elif int(x)==3:
        print("Goodbye then!")
        sys.exit()
```

It works fine, but on pressing option 3, it prints goodbye to the screen but then displays this error:

```
repl process died unexpectedly:
```

When I have used sys.exit in the past it just resorts to a simple exit (cursor flashing) and no error message.

What have I done wrong, and for teaching purposes, what are best practices here?

Comment: Instead of using `sys.exit()` method, why can't you `break` out of the `while` loop?

Comment: That does remove the error!

Comment: but still intrigued as to why I am getting the sys.exit() error in the first place..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggests you change the code to:

```py
while True:
    print("""
============MAIN MENU================
                   *Welcome*
                   1. Register
                   2. Login
                   3. Quit
""")
    
    x = int(input("Enter choice: "))
    if x == 1:
        register()
    elif x == 2:
        login()
    elif x == 3:
        print("Goodbye then!")
        break
```

It is not advisable to be using `sys.exit()` method in an iteration instead `break` out of the loop and perform all the necessary operation. As to why it raised an error, `sys.exit()` crashes the operation of the iteration and terminate the program. So it's always a good practice to `break` out of loop first.

Answer (score -1):

Because of the `sys.exit()` function, you are getting the error message that says,

```
repl process died unexpectedly:
```

Comment: Please read  [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)